# Resizable style left and right arrows

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I am trying to add 2 circles, left & right, to the resizable div and style them. I added them and it seems ok, but when I try to resize left of right the circles remain unchanged at the same position. The idea was to move circles with the resizable div. Can you help me please?

```js
$("#resizable").resizable({
  containment: "#image-container-step2",
  handles: "e,w"
});
```

```css
#resizable {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  top: 100px;
  /*left: 100px;*/
}

#resizable .resizers {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #4286f4;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#resizable .resizers .resizer {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  border: 3px solid #4286f4;
  position: absolute;
}

#resizable .resizers .resizer.left {
  left: -5px;
  top: -7px;
  cursor: w-resize;
  /*resizer cursor*/
}

#resizable .resizers .resizer.right {
  left: 190px;
  top: -7px;
  cursor: e-resize;
  /*resizer cursor*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<div id="resizable">
  <div class='resizers'>
    <div class="resizer left"></div>
    <div class="resizer right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your snippet is missing a reference to jQueryUI.js - is that a mistake in your actual code too?

Comment: Noooo......I put only a piece of html code not included added libraries

Comment: Ok, I've added a reference to jQueryUI in to the snippet for you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving `.resizer.right` `left: 190px` just give it `right: -5px`. Now if you resize it will be with the line. Hope it helps

Code updated and now it is re-sizable with circles as well

```js
$("#resizable").resizable({
  containment: "#resizable",
  handles: "e,w"
});
```

```css
#resizable {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  top: 100px;
  /*left: 100px;*/
}

#resizable .resizers {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #4286f4;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#resizable .resizers .resizer {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  border: 3px solid #4286f4;
  position: absolute;
}
#resizable .ui-resizable-handle{
    width: 31px;
    height: 31px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#resizable .resizers .resizer.left,#resizable .resizers .resizer.right{
top:50%;
transform:translateY(-50%);
}
#resizable .resizers .resizer.left {
  left: -5px;
  cursor: w-resize;
  /*resizer cursor*/
}

#resizable .resizers .resizer.right {
  right: -5px;
  cursor: e-resize;
  /*resizer cursor*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<div id="resizable">
  <div id="resizers" class='resizers'>
    <div class="resizer left"></div>
    <div class="resizer right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not the whole circle are draggable, have you an idea ?

Comment: @HareaCostea check now i updated the code and now circles are draggable. actually on js I didn't updated the id.

Comment: also added a css for handles so that it covers the circles and work with the circle.